# Can't escape character in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to escape " in a jquery string, however the " doesnt print. I am using \" to escape it.

```
$form.append(name +' <input type="checkbox" class="team" id="team" 
data-value1="age:'+ age +'" data-value2="fav_color = '  + color +' "/>


$form.append(name +' <input type="checkbox" class="team" id="team" 
data-value1="age: \"'+ age +' \"" data-value2="fav_color = \"'  + color +' "\"/>

 result = 'age: 12' for both
```

I need

```
 result = 'age: "12"'
```

Comment: I think you have to use the html encoded version of the quotes rather than escaping them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260195/escape-quotes-in-html5-data-attribute-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use html entities, eg.:

```
$form.append(name +' <input type="checkbox" class="team" id="team" data-value1="age:&quot;'+ age +'&quot;" data-value2="fav_color = '  + color +' "/>');
```